# DataSet with table with optional columns

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Is it possible to have one DataSet for databases that have table with optional columns. For example database 1 have table with ID, Text1 and database 2 have table with ID, Text1 and Text2?

Comment: yes you can add items to Columns collection of the datatable

Comment: By optional columns, do you mean columns that allow null values?

Comment: i think you can add any table to dataset and any number of rows in a table.    DataSet s = new DataSet();
            s.Tables.Add();
            s.Tables[index].Rows.Add();

Comment: I mean that there are 2 types of databases, one that have table without Text2 column and the other that have table with Text2 column.